# Multiple middleware routes with NextJS and next-auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I'm trying to exclude one path from next-auth using middleware file. As i understand i can use only one middleware under `app` structure. i tried to make what i need but i got in a small issue.
I want all routes to be under `next-auth` default middleware, and the `/api` route to have still need to have the token from authentication, however I want it to return an unauthorized message.

```
import { withAuth, NextRequestWithAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const { NEXTAUTH_URL = '' } = process.env;

export default withAuth(
  async function middleware(request: NextRequestWithAuth) {
    const response = NextResponse.next();

    if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/api')) {
      if (!request.nextauth.token) {
        return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: 'authentication failed' }), {
          status: 401,
          headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        });
      }
      response.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', NEXTAUTH_URL);
      response.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
      response.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    }
    //...
    return response;
  },
  {
    pages: {
      signIn: '/auth/signin',
    },
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ token }) => !!token,
    },
  },
);
```

But this doesn't work, it still redirect to login page if not logged in. Is there a way to run the `next-auth` middleware on specific paths or at least make it skip one itself?

The way they marketed the changes make believes is very flexible but i found it very restrictive.